# Oreo - View layout management has changed?

Tags: view, android-8.0-oreo

Don't flame me but prior to Oreo I used to put view in a static and keep it switching from fragments and it worked pretty well. In onCreate I simply check if the value of view is not null and in that case I was not inflating. It allowed me to do long task in a fragment in an async and switch to another fragment waiting for the async to complete.

It still works the same way with O except when I rotate the device. In that case I get a blank screen: no layout, no buttons, no text, etc.

I've read https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes but didn't find anything.

Do you have an idea to fix this without changing it all?

Answer (score 0):

From the way I understand it. if the Rotation is locked to portrait mode, rotating the device won't force it into landscape mode if portrait mode is locked.

Check out the following post:

[android-p-feature-spotlight-rotation-can-temporarily-locked-landscape-changes](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/03/08/android-p-feature-spotlight-rotation-can-temporarily-locked-landscape-changes/)

> Just as annoying as Android Oreo, and unlike most OEM versions of Android I've used. There are new APIs for screen rotation in Android P so it's not clear whether apps need to implement it to be able to lock to landscape from the first go.

Also check out the **Android P preview** for more info regarding the rotation changes, for some reason it appears to be relevant for the **Android Oreo** as well.

[Feature Overview](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/03/08/android-p-feature-spotlight-rotation-can-temporarily-locked-landscape-changes/)

[Behaviour Overview](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes#screen-rotation-changes)